# Пагинация записей плагина WordPress WPAdverts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Хочу сразу попросить, не минусуйте вопрос, пжлст. Впервые работаю на wordpress, и мне поставлена задача найти плагин для подачи объявлений и адаптировать его на сайт. Плагин используется вот этот - `WPAdverts`, а вот линк на его [демо](https://wpadverts.com/demo/). Использую только этот плагин, так как это единственный совместимый плагин с версией wp, на котором построен сайт. Были проблемы с загрузкой галереи, но я это починил. Теперь всё работает хорошо! НО за исключением одного момента. Пагинация работает некорректно. Для пагинации установил 5 видимых записей. В общем, когда выбираешь категорию (Куплю или Продам), то фильтр работает хорошо, но почему-то пагинация может отображать неверную градацию чисел. Например, появиться 3 записи по фильтру, а пагинация будет такой `1 2 3 ... 9`, хотя по факту всего 3 записи, не больше. Фильтр по категориям делаю линком `http://agro.ssomsk.ru/advert-category/продам`. Вот урл проекта с объявлениями - http://agro.ssomsk.ru/adverts. Можете сами попробовать, что бы лучше понять проблему. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: И как попробовать, когда там базовая аутентификация на входе?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, не учел что-то этого момента.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, может быть у вас есть предположения о том, почему такая проблема с пагинацией? или вам все же нужен доступ?

Comment: Предположений нет, надо дебажить. Отключайте все плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную. Возможно, поймёте источник проблемы

Comment: @KAGGDesign, такое чувство, словно при переходе на категория (на пример "Продам") отображается та пагинация, которая не имеет отношения к этим выбранным объявлениям. - https://ibb.co/qxF1L1X

Comment: Чувства тут не помогут.

Comment: и когда нажимаю на кнопку "Править" (на скрине она изображена), то попадаю в админку вордпресс, в раздел со всеми записями, которые не являются объявлениями.

Comment: Скорее всего, объектам присвоено несколько категорий. Но это всё гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно дать совет без отладки, не видя вашего сайта. Попробуйте стандартную методику: отключайте все плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную. Возможно, найдёте источник проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло :)